# when element is clicked get the index and then pass that to trigger another event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lots of duplicated parents each with 8 .fader-empty divs inside.   I am trying to get the number of the child div when clicked (which seems to be working) but then I am trying to pass the index number so that I can add a class to each 2nd parent with the the same index.

So for example I click on the 3rd child div. It should grap the 2nd parent and add a class (highlight) the 3rd child div in that one also.

I hope that makes sense.

This is all I could manage so far:

```
$('.fader-empty').click(
    function(){
        var index = $(this).index();
        alert(index);
        $('.fader-section').find('.fader-empty:nth-child(3)').addClass('shoo');

});
```

This is a [**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/58d6e3gx/).

Comment: a little hard to imagine, at least for me, what you are trying to do without looking at your HTML. possible to share?

Comment: Sorry yes it is probably easier with the html to show what I mean. I've made a demo as the html has to be duplicated to show exactly what I need to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/58d6e3gx/

Comment: What I'm trying to do is when you click on one of those individual blocks I want the all the blocks directly underneath it to highlight. Currently When I click I can only make the 3rd one in each block highlight but it is highlighting the 3rd ones in everyblock.

Comment: so in a nutshell I just want to be able to click one and it makes a highlighted line of all the blocks underneath.  Really can't begin to figure out how to do this though.

Comment: @SuziLarsen still unable to understand what should happen if i click on the first block's 1st column.?

Comment: if you click on the first ever column it should find the exact same one in the rows below (new-layer) and highlight those ones

Comment: @SuziLarsen: posted an answer. Hope this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace the `3` with `(index + 1)`, *because index begins from 0*, this is how should be your code :

```
$('.fader-empty').click(

   function () {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('.fader-section').find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('shoo');

});
```

And this is **[your Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58d6e3gx/2/)**.

**EDIT:**

To exactly match the sections vertically above the clicked element, I used this code:

```
$('.fader-empty').click(function () {
    var faderIndex = $(this).index();
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    var parentIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    $('.fader-section').each(function () {
        if ($(this).index() === parentIndex) {
            $(this).find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (faderIndex + 1) + ')').addClass('shoo');
        }
    });
});
```

You have to proceed like this:

1. Get the index of the clicked element parent section
2. And then iterate over the same class sections and only change the ones with the same index.

This is **[the updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/58d6e3gx/9/)** again.

Comment: that is much better yes!!  One more thing? Is there a way to isolate that fader-section that you clicked on so it ignores the other fader sections? So if I pressed on say a fader-empty in the 2nd or 4th  fader section div it would only highlight the ones above and below for that specific fader-section.

Comment: sorry that was rather long winded hope it makes sense

Comment: I've managed to do something by using the same idea that you started with. Not sure how "proper" it is but it seems to be working

http://jsfiddle.net/susannalarsen/qwkn4yhc/

Comment: I used your idea and just applied it to this also. It works!

Comment: @SuziLarsen Yes It works great approach, I used another code but with the same logic and it's working too, take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: @Suzi: while it's your prerogative to choose the answer you accept, please take a moment to consider if this is the genuinely the *best* answer to your problem. I'd suggest that the answer is lacking both detail and explanation which, while you might be able to understand it (and therefore it may genuinely be the best answer from your perspective), I strongly doubt that it's of much use to subsequent viewers and users of the site that aren't so familiar with jQuery. Please understand that this is in no way intended to promote my own answer, just a request that you consider this answer's use.

Comment: @DavidThomas  Thank you for pointing it out, I updated the answer and  included the explanation.

Comment: Thank you, my apologies for any offence I may have caused, I hadn't meant my last comment to sound so churlish.

Comment: @DavidThomas No it's fine, you are right after all and I shouldn't miss it anyway.

Comment: All of the answers provided worked great.  I think it is just that this answer was just the most helpful to me as I could understand it a little bit easier.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question it seems that the requirements are to highlight the `.fader-empty` cells of the `.fader-section` elements that appear in the 'columns' below (and presumably above) the `.fader-empty` element that you click.

To do that it would make sense, and is almost a pre-requisite (unless you're operating in a very closed and controlled environment), to first identify the column in which the element you're clicking is in, and then, after finding the index of the element you click, applying the given class-name to all other elements of that same index in that same column.

To do that I'd suggest the following:

```
// first a simple jQuery plug-in to identify the columns:
(function ($) {
    $.fn.identifyColumn = function () {

        // initialising the column-count at 0:
        var column = 0,

        // finding the offset().top position of
        // the first element of the collection:
            topOffset = this.eq(0).offset().top;

        // iterating over each element in the collection
        // here 'this' is the jQuery object/collection,
        // itself, inside the each() loop 'this' refers
        //  to individual elements inside of that
        // jQuery object/collection:
        return this.each(function () {

            // setting the 'data-column' attribute using
            // attr() instead of data(), because I want
            // the column to be amongst the element's
            // attributes, not held in jQuery's data-store
            // (which is initialised by data-* attributes,
            // but the attributes are not updated by
            // setting new data properties with the data()
            // method):
            $(this).attr('data-column', function () {

                // caching the $(this):
                var self = $(this);

                // if the offset().top is the same as
                // the established topOffset then we
                // can infer that we're on the same 'row'
                // as a corollary, if the offset().top
                // is different we can infer we're on a
                // new row:
                if (topOffset !== self.offset().top) {

                    // updating the topOffset with the
                    // offset().top of the new 'row':
                    topOffset = self.offset().top;

                    // resetting the column counter:
                    column = 0;
                }

                // returning the column+<integer> string:
                return 'column' + ++column;
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

// selecting the '.fader-section' elements, and
// applying the plugin:
$('.fader-section').identifyColumn()

    // finding the '.fader-empty' elements within
    // the '.fader-section' elements, and binding
    // an anonymous event-handler for the 'click'
    // event:
    .find('.fader-empty').on('click', function () {

    // caching '$(this)' for subsequent use:
    var self = $(this),

        // finding the index of the clicked element:
        index = self.index(),

        // finding the closest '.fader-section' ancestor,
        // and retrieving its 'data-column' attribute value:
        column = self.closest('.fader-section').attr('data-column');

    // selecting all '.fader-section' elements, and
    // filtering that collection to only those that share
    // the same 'data-column' attribute-value:
    $('.fader-section').filter(function () {
        return this.dataset.column === column;

    // looking within the retained '.fader-section' elements
    // for the '.fader-empty' descendant elements which
    // are also at the equivalent index, using the CSS
    // ':nth-child()' selector, which requires increasing
    // the found index number by 1 (JavaScript is zero-based,
    // CSS is 1-based); and then adding the 'shoo' class to
    // those elements:
    }).find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('shoo');

});
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.identifyColumn = function() {
    var column = 0,
      topOffset = this.eq(0).offset().top;
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).attr('data-column', function() {
        var self = $(this);

        if (topOffset !== self.offset().top) {
          topOffset = self.offset().top;
          column = 0;
        }

        return 'column' + ++column;
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.fader-section').identifyColumn()
  .find('.fader-empty').on('click', function() {
    var self = $(this),
      index = self.index(),
      column = self.closest('.fader-section').attr('data-column');

    $('.fader-section').filter(function() {
      return this.dataset.column === column;
    }).find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('shoo');

  });
```

```css
.new-layer {
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.sub-layer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.fader-section {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.fader-empty {
  background-color: #e5e7ea;
  border-left: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-top: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  height: 100px;
  width: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.shoo {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--new layer-->
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--new layer-->
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ejpmdkkj/), for experimentation/development.

Further to the above, with a single minor change, I've added the opportunity to remove the `.shoo` class-name from previously-selected elements:

```
$('.fader-section').identifyColumn()
    .find('.fader-empty').on('click', function () {
    var self = $(this),
        index = self.index(),
        column = self.closest('.fader-section').attr('data-column');

    // this line is the only addition, and simply removes
    // the '.shoo' class-name from all elements that have
    // that class-name:
    $('.shoo').removeClass('shoo');

    $('.fader-section').filter(function () {
        return this.dataset.column === column;
    }).find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('shoo');

});
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.identifyColumn = function() {
    var column = 0,
      topOffset = this.eq(0).offset().top;
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).attr('data-column', function() {
        var self = $(this);

        if (topOffset !== self.offset().top) {
          topOffset = self.offset().top;
          column = 0;
        }

        return 'column' + ++column;
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.fader-section').identifyColumn()
  .find('.fader-empty').on('click', function() {
    var self = $(this),
      index = self.index(),
      column = self.closest('.fader-section').attr('data-column');

    $('.fader-section').filter(function() {
      return this.dataset.column === column;
    }).find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('shoo');

  });
```

```css
.new-layer {
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.sub-layer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.fader-section {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.fader-empty {
  background-color: #e5e7ea;
  border-left: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-top: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  height: 100px;
  width: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.shoo {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--new layer-->
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--new layer-->
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ejpmdkkj/1/), for experimentation/development.

Or, if you'd prefer, you could have only one `.shoo` class in each of the identified columns, by amending the above selector:

```
$('.fader-section').identifyColumn()
    .find('.fader-empty').on('click', function () {
    var self = $(this),
        index = self.index(),
        column = self.closest('.fader-section').attr('data-column');

    // selecting all '.fader-section' elements with a
    // 'data-column' attribute-value equal to that
    // of the 'column' in which we clicked, and finding
    // only the '.shoo' elements in that single 'column'
    // then removing the 'shoo' class from only those
    // elements, leaving other 'columns' untouched:
    $('.fader-section[data-column=' + column + '] .shoo').removeClass('shoo');
    $('.fader-section').filter(function () {
        return this.dataset.column === column;
    }).find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('shoo');

});
```

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.identifyColumn = function() {
    var column = 0,
      topOffset = this.eq(0).offset().top;
    return this.each(function() {
      $(this).attr('data-column', function() {
        var self = $(this);

        if (topOffset !== self.offset().top) {
          topOffset = self.offset().top;
          column = 0;
        }

        return 'column' + ++column;
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('.fader-section').identifyColumn()
  .find('.fader-empty').on('click', function() {
    var self = $(this),
      index = self.index(),
      column = self.closest('.fader-section').attr('data-column');

    $('.fader-section[data-column=' + column + '] .shoo').removeClass('shoo');
    $('.fader-section').filter(function() {
      return this.dataset.column === column;
    }).find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('shoo');

  });
```

```css
.new-layer {
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.sub-layer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.fader-section {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.fader-empty {
  background-color: #e5e7ea;
  border-left: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-top: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  height: 100px;
  width: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.shoo {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--new layer-->
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<!--new layer-->
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ejpmdkkj/2/), for experimentation/development.

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS attribute-equals (`[attribute=value]`) selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
  - [`:nth-child()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo).
- JavaScript:

  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
  - [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 1):

Is **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/yzwc8a79/2/embedded/result/)** the kind of effect you are after?

***Snippet:***

```js
var newLayers = $('.new-layer');
var subLayers = $('.sub-layer');
var faderSections = $('.fader-section');
var faderEmpties = $('.fader-empty');
faderEmpties.click(function() {
  var faderEmptyIndex = $(this).index();
  var faderSectionIndex = $(this).parent().index();
  var subLayerIndex = $(this).parent().parent().index();
  var newLayerIndex = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
  subLayers.each(function() {
    $(this)
      .find('.fader-section')
      .eq(faderSectionIndex)
      .find('.fader-empty')
      .eq(faderEmptyIndex)
      .toggleClass('shoo');
  });
});
```

```css
.new-layer {
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: left;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.sub-layer {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.fader-section {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.fader-empty {
  background-color: #e5e7ea;
  border-left: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-top: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
  height: 240px;
  width: 44px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.shoo {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="new-layer">
  <div class="sub-layer">
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="fader-section">
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
      <div class="fader-empty"></div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

***Details:***

- The idea is to iterate through `subLayers` elements.
- `.find()` all of `.fader-section` elements within it.
- out of all those `.fader-section` elements, only get a specific by the use of `.eq()` method.
- Further `.find()` all of `.fader-empty` elements within that.
- and out of those, only get a specific one.
- and finally, `.toggleClass()` on it.

Just thought I should add details for the curious ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just add :odd to your first selector to select ever 2nd parent (i.e. the 2nd, 4th, etc.)

I also replaced 3 with (index + 1) - note that it's 1 indexed (not 0 indexed)

```
$('.fader-section:odd').find('.fader-empty:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('shoo');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.fader-empty').click(
    function(){        
    var blockIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
        $(this).parents('.new-layer').find('.fader-section').find('.fader-empty:nth-child('+ blockIndex +')').addClass('shoo');
  
});
```

```css
.new-layer {
 clear:both;
 white-space:nowrap;
 float:left;
 background:#f1f1f1;
 padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;
 font-size:0;
}
.sub-layer {
 margin-top:10px;
}
.fader-section {
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
}
.fader-empty {
 background-color:#e5e7ea;
 border-left:1px solid #a1a1a1;
 border-top:1px solid #a1a1a1;
 border-bottom:1px solid #a1a1a1;
 height:240px;
 width:44px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 font-size:12px;
 cursor:pointer;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
.shoo {
    background-color:green !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="new-layer">
            <div class="sub-layer">
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>


<!--new layer-->

<div class="new-layer">
            <div class="sub-layer">
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
<!--new layer-->

<div class="new-layer">
            <div class="sub-layer">
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
              <section class="fader-section">
               <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
                <div class="fader-empty"></div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
```

here is updated jsfiddle of your code

[Demo Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58d6e3gx/1/)

Comment: @Suzi Larsen please check out the answer

Comment: Yes sort of.  except when you click on one it should highlight the one you clicked on but instead of highlight going left and right it should grab the ones directly above and below and highlight in a vertical line.

Comment: @SuziLarsen hey are you want to show highlighted to the every new-layer's element or what.?

Comment: its to show a highlight in a strip.  Ideally when you click on something it would highlight every block above and below (fader-empty blocks) but nothing to the right and the left

Comment: I should say that by above and below I mean visually.  There is probably confusion to that as it could be intepreted as the html that is above and below. Just visually